# Algolia: Filter if attribute exists

Tags: node.js, algolia

For the below data

```
[
  {
    "name": "iPhone XR Black 64GB",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "iPhone XS Gold 64GB",
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "Galaxy Note9 Ocean Blue 128GB",
  },
  {
    "name": "G7 ThinQ™ Platinum Gray 64GB",
  },
  {
    "name": "Moto E5 Play 16GB",
  }
]
```

If I filter color:red it should return the records matching the following criterias.

1. If the color attribute exists it should be red.
2. If the color attribute doesn't exist.

Output would be

```
[
  {
    "name": "iPhone XR Black 64GB",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "Galaxy Note9 Ocean Blue 128GB",
  },
  {
    "name": "G7 ThinQ™ Platinum Gray 64GB",
  },
  {
    "name": "Moto E5 Play 16GB",
  }
]
```

[**Click here for flow chart**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TZyN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Algolia is a search engine, meaning that it returns matching records as is. It doesn't perform any transformations, and you can't inject logic into the engine's behavior.

With your above dataset, if you run an empty search (`''`) with a filter `"color:red"`, Algolia will only return the following record:

```json
{
  "name": "iPhone XR Black 64GB",
  "color": "red"
}
```

If you want all records (in the limit of 1,000 records), you need to perform an empty query with no filters.